# Shopware Giving error on local envirnoment and Run fine on staging

Tags: php, shopware

I have downloaded the shopware from staging server and integrated there code and DB but when run the backend URL get below error with shopware version 4.3.0

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Shopware_Plugins_Core_HttpCache_Bootstrap::onPreDispatch() must be an instance of Enlight_Controller_EventArgs, instance of Enlight_Controller_ActionEventArgs given, called in /home/verve/projects/shop/engine/Library/Enlight/Event/Handler/Plugin.php on line 149 and defined in /home/verve/projects/shop/engine/Shopware/Plugins/Default/Core/HttpCache/Bootstrap.php:323 Stack trace: #0 /home/verve/projects/shop/engine/Library/Enlight/Event/Handler/Plugin.php(149): Shopware_Plugins_Core_HttpCache_Bootstrap->onPreDispatch(Object(Enlight_Controller_ActionEventArgs)) #1 /home/verve/projects/shop/engine/Library/Enlight/Event/EventManager.php(211): Enlight_Event_Handler_Plugin->execute(Object(Enlight_Controller_ActionEventArgs)) #2 /home/verve/projects/shop/engine/Library/Enlight/Controller/Action.php(137): Enlight_Event_EventManager->notify('Enlight_Control...', Object(Enlight_Controller_ActionEventArgs)) #3 /home/verve/projects/shop/engine/Library/Enlight/Controller/Dispatcher/ in /home/verve/projects/shop/engine/Shopware/Plugins/Default/Core/HttpCache/Bootstrap.php on line 323

503 Service Unavailable

Comment: Do you use the same PHP version locally and on staging? Does your frontend work well?

Comment: I think @PawełNapierała right. Probably your staging server has php5.6, but production php7+.

Comment: Now working but when i am going to do "{url}/recovery/update" its giving me below error in step 4

Type: Zend_Json_Exception
Message: Decoding failed: Syntax error